# best desktop or webscript for managing database?

Tags: database

which one is best web script or preferably desktop software in which my small company can keep database of students and teachers and do stuff like sorting, filtering, and giving command to print certificate for selected students on demand.

thanks

Comment: Surely there is dedicated school administration softeare out there?

Comment: Do you want a database or something to manage a database?

Comment: i am not sure what it will be called.
i use access but its too complicated for all my work pals to understand...i need some functionality of access in an easy way which is like simple to use...more like a software that uses a database at backend  and all i have to do is to put data generate stuff sort stuff and print certificates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a simple database with user interface for managing small amounts of data, [OpenOffice Base](http://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html) is free to download and use. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

**Update:** If you are willing for your data to be public or willing to pay a small monthly sum, you could also consider [Dabble DB](http://dabbledb.com/).

Comment: can u tell me instead of database, any software that i can use for this purpose so that all i see is user interface and database runs at back.

Comment: thanks a lot, dabble db might work for us, but if u happen to find a  desktop software that has user interface like dabble db that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) and avoid the overhead of having a database server installed for the application to run.

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) - SQLite is an ACID-compliant embedded relational database management system contained in a relatively small (~225 KB) C programming library.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://wikipedia.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Download and use a php, apache, and mysql bundle like XAMPP (www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).  It  is easy to install, configure and have a working web based database application with a few hours of work. You will need to use mail merge in Microsoft PowerPoint if you want decent looking certificates.

Comment: how will i use mail merge in power point to print certificates...is there a tutorial?

Comment: PowerPoint does not support mail merge out of the box. You can get the functionality using a third party plugin like the one available at http://www.pptools.com/merge/index.html . The plugin costs about $20. Another option is to print the certificates from Microsoft Word. It has a very powerful feature set for mail merge.